# Nokogiriのgemがインストールできない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

はじめまして、Ruby初心者のものです。
スクレイピングをしてみたいと思い、Nokogiriのgemをインストールをしようとしたのですが、エラーが出てしまい、それに対応していたら最終的に下記のようなエラーになり全く太刀打ちができなくなってしまいました。
ご協力してもらえるとありがたいです><

```
$ gem install nokogiri            [/Users/yukito/dev/scraping]
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/yukito/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/.autotest
```

初歩的な質問になってしまい申し訳ないのですが、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

おそらく $ sudo gem install xxx を実行してしまい、/Users/アカウント名/.rbenv配下にアクセスできなくなったのではないでしょうか？
以下のサイトに解決方法？かどうかはわかりませんが、対処方法が記載されています。
https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/930

> $ sudo chown -R YOURUSER:staff /Users/me/.rbenv

Answer (score -1):

以下のコマンドを実行してみてください。

```
$ rbenv rehash
```

上手くいかないようでしたら、`gem env` で出力した結果を載せて頂いた方が回答者が回答しやすくなると思います。